# PRAW filter NSFW

Tags: python, praw

I just got python and I am making a reddit scraper with PRAW.

I am trying to filter out NSFW posts and I have read over the docs and cannot find much about it.
This is my current code:

```
import praw

*my api key things*

top_posts = reddit.subreddit('examplesubreddit').top(limit=2, time_filter="day")

for submission in top_memes:
    print(submission.title)
```

In the [PRAW docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) there is a [over_18 attribute](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html?highlight=nsfw) but whenever I run:

```
import praw

*my api key things*

top_posts = reddit.subreddit('examplesubreddit').top(limit=2, time_filter="day", over_18=false)

for submission in top_memes:
    print(submission.title)
```

I get an error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'over_18'
```

Any ideas on how to filter this search to not include NSFW posts?

Comment: Try using `False` not `false` check case

Comment: Ok I would have been very mad if that was the error but whenever I change the false to capital it runs the error: 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'over_18'

Its just that over_18 is not defined and I am looking for something that will work like that

Comment: Post that error then, but writing false wrong wouldn't work, please post complete code, how we can understand what exactly your constructor contains?

Comment: Ok there it is!

Comment: Since attributes are dynamically provided [(see Determine Available Attributes of an Object)](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object), there is not a guarantee that these attributes will always be present, nor is this list necessarily complete. check if `try`,`catch` works for you